# How can I find out which pages on my website have high CLS?

Tags: web, pagespeed, cls, cumulative-layout-shift

When testing various pages from my website on pagespeed.web.dev I get real CLS under 0.1 for most of them but I still have core web vitals failed for desktop because it seems that I have like under 30% of pages with CLS higher than 0.1.

The thing is that I have yet to find a page that has over 0.1, I need to know how can I find those pages so I know what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a [suggested workflow](https://web.dev/articles/vitals-tools#step_1_evaluate_website_health_and_identify_opportunities_for_improvement) for optimizing Core Web Vitals. In your case, you know your site has a CLS issue, but you're not sure where. The recommended tools to identify which pages need improvement are:

> 1. Use PageSpeed Insights to view overall Core Web Vitals experience metrics on the origin, and specific information on an individual URL. (**you've done this**)
> 2. [Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) can be useful to identify pages which need improvement where its page grouping feature works well for your site.
> 3. If you have RUM data, then that is often the best option to be able to identify particular pages or traffic segments with issues.

So your next step should be to check Search Console, which will identify groups of similar pages with CLS issues. Or, even better, [measure your Core Web Vitals yourself](https://web.dev/articles/vitals-field-measurement-best-practices).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found some links in search console that say that have CLS higher than 0.1 but when testing them on pagespeed I always get way under 0.1, sometimes 0.0X so great results. What’s the next step now?

Comment: For the pages that Search Console says are contributing to poor CLS, can you confirm that PageSpeed Insights is showing you URL-level data, and both the real-user and lab-based CLS scores are good? Sometimes a page won't have enough real-user data for an assessment, but the lab tests might find CLS issues. When in doubt, collecting your own RUM data will tell you exactly which pages have issues, and you can even collect attribution info to know what is causing the layout shifts.

Comment: Hi. There isn’t enough data to show real user CLS, it shows the general CLS. But then testing a lot of pages on pagespeed I always get CLS smaller than 0.1.

Comment: Ok so it seems like Search Console is detecting poor CLS on these pages in aggregate, but there's not enough data for individual pages to have their own real-user CLS score. If the synthetic CLS score is good, then there may be layout shifts happening in response to user interactions like scrolling. As I said, the best thing to do would be to measure CLS yourself with RUM. But if you want to get to the bottom of it sooner, use something like the Web Vitals extension for Chrome or the Performance panel of DevTools to monitor layout shifts as you use the page locally.

Comment: And if you're curious why Search Console is saying there are CLS issues on the page, but that's not what the synthetic CLS score in PageSpeed Insights says, read this article: https://web.dev/articles/lab-and-field-data-differences#cls